# Proof: Brownian motion has no intervals of monotonicity

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, monotone-functions

I quote *Morters-Peres (2010)*. My observations/questions in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.

> **Theorem** Almost surely, for all $0<a<b<\infty$, Brownian motion $\left(B_t\right)_t$ is not monotone on the interval $[a,b]$.
> **Proof** Fix a nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$. If it is an interval of monotonicity, then we pick numbers $a=a_1\le\ldots\le a_{n+1}=b$ and divide $[a,b]$ into $n$ sub-intervals $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$. Each increment $B(a_{i+1})-B(a_i)$ has to have the same sign. As the increments are independent (by definition), this has probability $2\cdot2^{-n}$, and taking $n\to\infty$ shows that probability that $[a,b]$ is an interval of monotonicity must be zero. 
> $\color{red}{\text{(So far so good to me and I am believing that this suffices to prove the above theorem,}}$ 
> $\color{red}{\text{doesn't it?)}}$
>  Taking a countable union gives that, almost surely, there is no nondegenerate interval of monotonicity with rational endpoints, but each nondegenerate interval would have a nondegenerate rational sub-interval. 
> $\color{red}{\text{(I cannot really understand the immediately above statement. Is it crucial to conclude}}$
> $\color{red}{\text{the proof of the above theorem? If so, why? And what does it mean?}}$
> $\color{red}{\text{Why are 
> "countable union", "rational endpoints" and "rational sub-intervals" recalled?}}$  
>  $\color{red}{\text{Could you please help me understand this part with a detailed answer?)}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, by taking the countable union, the author shows that the Brownian motion is not monotonic in $[a,b]$ under the assumption that $[a,b]$ can only be decomposed as a countable union of intervals with rational endpoints (rational endpoints because is a countable union). But he has to prove it for an interval without the assumption above. Technically **it could exists an interval with non-rational endpoints that hasn't been considered**. So by saying: "...each nondegenrate interval would have a nondegenerate rational sub-interval", he argues that that the bold statement is not possible. The reason is that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ so every generic interval contains an interval with rational endpoints.

Comment: So, if I properly understand, you mean that he considers a nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$ such that $[a,b]$ can be seen as a countable union of intervals with rational endpoints, and shows that Brownian motion is not monotonic on it. To show that this is sufficient to prove the result for *every* possible $[a, b]$, he says that "...each nondegenrate interval would have a nondegenerate rational sub-interval", given by the fact that set of rational numbers  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, correct? **[continue]**

Comment: **[continue]** Finally, when considering $[a,b]$ as a countable union of intervals, such intervals forming the union is said to have **rational** endpoints since the union is countable (and set of rational sumbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable)? Could he have stated that $[a,b]$ can be seen as a countable union of intervals with **integer** endpoints (given that set of integer numbers $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable just like $\mathbb{Q}$)? However, I suspect this would not have been a good approach since, unlike $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, correct?

Comment: Yes to everything you said in both comments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here is that the theorem is claiming that, w.p. 1, the Brownian path is non-monotonic on *every* interval, simultaneously. What the first part shows is that, if you are given any arbitrary interval (but only one), the path is non-monotonic on it w.p. 1. Since there are uncountably many possible intervals, some additional arguments are required to show that non-monotonicity still holds for all of them, jointly, w.p. 1.

I think this has a somewhat similar flavor to the distinction between two processes being modifications of each other vs. being indistinguishable. In one case, they are equal w.p. 1 at any given time value. In the other, the joint probability of them being equal at *every* time value is 1.

Comment: Very good point. However, what is the role - in the reasoning - of "rational endpoints" and "rational sub-intervals"?

Comment: I think the purpose of this is to replace an intersection over uncountably many choices of $a<b$ with one over countably many _rational_ $a<b$. One then argues that a.s. non-monotonicity over this intersection is sufficient to show it for all intervals.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see what you mean. I cannot really understand the meaning of "Taking a countable union gives that, almost surely, there is no nondegenerate interval of monotonicity with rational endpoints, but each nondegenrate interval would have a nondegenerate rational sub-interval". Could you please restate it in some other way? Here, it seems to me the author is referring to union, not to intersection @svensvenson

Comment: I also have trouble parsing the author's wording. But if I had to use "a.s. non-monotonicity on any given interval" to prove "a.s. non-monotonicity on all intervals jointly," this is what I would do. A countable intersection of a.s. events is a.s., so I would take it over all rational $a,b$. I would then argue that this is sufficient to ensure the property for _all_ $a,b$. Supposing $a,b$ are irrational and the Brownian path is monotonic on $\left[a,b\right]$, you can find a subinterval with rational endpoints over which the property should not hold.